# The speed of light and sound in materials

Tags: relativity

Obviously, nothing moves faster than the speed of light in a vacuum. Light propagates through materials slower than in a vacuum, and that rate is often related to the specific frequency. Is there a material through which light and sound at the same frequency would propagate at a similar rate?

Could sound ever travel through a material more quickly than light?

Could sound, at a certain frequency, travel through a material more quickly than light of a different frequency?

Comment: googling "sound faster than light" gives many relevant results

Comment: Yes, it has been observed both in the lab, see for instance http://phys.org/news/2007-01-mach-scientists-faster.html and it is suppossed to hapen in the interior of stars

Comment: Intuitively we can see that the math would work out, so the only problem would be can we actually fabricate a material with such qualities (or maybe it already exists)? If we can make materials that have a negative index of refraction, I'm sure we can manage.